# Javascript method argument escape

Tags: javascript

The below span tag containing an `onclick` event is not working

```
var test="<span onClick="gotoNode(\'' + result.name + '\',\'' + result.xaxis + '\',\'' + result.yaxis + '\',\'' + result.detail + '\',\'' + result.status + '\')" />"
```

the above escaped string has some problems with the method call.

How can I fix it?

Comment: fix your question pls? It is not clear what you want

Comment: Try not to use inline javascript.

Comment: Removing the example code probably wasn't the best edit.

Comment: @DavidThomas edit doesn't match the original code...

Comment: @Klors: does it not? I added two line breaks, one before and one after the code.

Comment: @DavidThomas there was a leading and trailing ', maybe someone else's edit before your's may have changed it, I haven't looked at the trail

Comment: @DavidThomas it looks like the original poster was editing it under you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're creating this in JavaScript to create an element, then the first single-quote needs to be escaped.

```js
function gotoNode(name, xaxis, yaxis, detail, status) {
  alert("name = " + name + "\r\nxaxis = " + xaxis + "\r\nyaxis = " + yaxis + "\r\ndetail = " + detail + "\r\nstatus = " + status);
}

var result = { name: "name", xaxis: "xaxis", yaxis: "yaxis", detail: "detail", status: "status" };

var htmlText = '<input value="Button" type="button" onclick="gotoNode(\'' + result.name + '\',\'' + result.xaxis + '\',\'' + result.yaxis + '\',\'' + result.detail + '\',\'' + result.status + '\')" />';

$("#lonely").append(htmlText);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lonely"></div>
```

Generally speaking, whatever quote type you begin with (out of `'` or `"`), you need to escape the same type that you want to use within the string and not escape the same type to terminate the string. You can leave the other type without escapes.

For your edited version, this should work if you want those result variables to be replaced with their values.

```
var test = "<span onclick=\"gotoNode('" + result.name + "','" + result.xaxis + "','" + result.yaxis + "','" + result.detail + "','" + result.status + "')\" />";
```

Comment: This doesn't work showing error in console - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string. method call doesn't happen

Comment: You need to have a `function gotoNode(){}` and a `result` object defined somewhere

Comment: var htmlText = '<input type="button" onclick="gotoNode(\'' + result.name + '\',\'' + result.xaxis + '\',\'' + result.yaxis + '\',\'' + result.detail + '\',\'' + result.status + '\')" />';

Comment: i also have function, without parameter coming inside the method

Comment: issue happens only when i have these escaped parameters. i don't how to escape exactly without error

Comment: @udhaya See my example function

Comment: working fine.. i did one minor syntax error thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Do you use php to generate the output?

Then you should try

```
echo "<input type=\"button\" onClick=\"gotoNode(\" + result.name + \",\" + 
result.xaxis + \",\" + result.yaxis + \",\" + result.detail + \",\" + 
result.status + \")\" />";
```